# Adding two formatted strings together? Python 3.5.2 tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

In python, using tkinter, I'm slowly creating a calculator in python, but using tkinter as the input. Here is what I have done so far:

```
from tkinter import *

first = ""
second = ""
c = Tk()
c.title("Calculator")
c.geometry("500x500")
c.configure(bg='orange')
a = Label(c, text="Enter First Number", font="-weight bold", bg='orange')
a.pack()
first = Entry(c)
first.pack()
b = Label(c, text="Enter Second Number", font="-weight bold",bg='orange')
b.pack()
second = Entry(c)
second.pack()

def add():
    first.get()
    second.get()
    print('{} + {} = '.format(first.get(), second.get()))
    print(first.get() + second.get())

def bp():
    add()

confirm1 = Button(c, text="Add Together", font="-weight bold", bg='orange', command=bp)
confirm1.pack()

mainloop()
```

I'm trying to make the two numbers (first and second) add together e.g.
If `first = 3` and `second = 5` I would want to add them together, making the output `3 + 5 = 8`. It seems that + only adds the numbers next to each other, not mathematically. I tried using +=, yet I got the error `Syntax Error: invalid syntax`. I'm not currently sure what I can do, and thats why I'm here. Thanks for reading this, and I do apologise for my bad english skills. Thank you :)

Comment: You'll have to convert your strings to a numeric type.

Comment: how exactly can I convert my strings to numeric type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `+` operator is overrided in strings to allow for concatenation of the left-hand side argument and right-hand side argument. You must explicitly convert both arguments to integers first, using `int()`.

```
>>> summation = int(first.get()) + int(second.get()) # first = 3, second = 5
>>> print('{} + {} = {}'.format(first.get(), second.get(), summation))
3 + 5 = 8
```